# Update: Send the origin header with js websockets

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I've been playing around with gorilla-websocket in Go, and as I implemented the basic echo example, I logged an error after deploying the server,

> Origin is not found
>   Websocket version != 13

I found a way to bypass this by making the function that checks the origin always return true

```
var wsUpgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}
```

But it doesn't feel right. Therefore, I am looking for a way to fix that issue.

Update: After having another look at the issue it seems like I'm actually looking to add the origin header to the client implementation which is the javascript websocket implementation

@benjic
Im connecting to the websocket via a javascript html5 application that isn't hosted on the same server but is run locally by me via chrome

So how do I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading through the [Gorilla WebSocket Documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) indicates that when a nil value is provided for the `CheckOrigin` field of an [`Upgrader`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Upgrader) type a safe default is used. The default checks the **Origin** field of the incoming request with the **Host** header value to confirm they are equal before allowing the request. The documentation indicates that browsers do not enforce cross origin validity and it is the responsibility of the server application to enforce. You can see exactly how this is done in the [source code](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/server.go#L61) for the Gorilla library.

The documentation and source indicate an [`Upgrade`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Upgrade) function in the `websocket` package that acts as a factory for your example code above. [The factory function](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/server.go#L223) takes a custom buffer size and overrides the CheckOrigin to always return true. Instead of creating a custom `Upgrader` you can use this factory function in the `HttpHandler` to upgrade your connections.

```
func webSocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r, nil, 1024, 1024)
    defer conn.Close()

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello, world!"))
}
```

Comment: Check the Origin header of the WebSocket handshake request on the server, since that header was designed to protect the server against attacker-initiated cross-site connections of victim browsers!
Use session-individual random tokens (like CSRF-Tokens) on the handshake request and verify them on the server.that is a quote from a websocket security blog i was reading.And so doesn't the empty CheckOrigin function cause any security vulnerabilities? @CodingPickle

Comment: @Whiteclaws If you want to use the default CheckOrigin function you need to ensure that your client library includes the Origin header with it's request. If you update the question to include your architecture I can update my answer to reflect the update.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy your html to a server, e.g nginx or just use node to start. Then it will get a hostname & port in browser.

Then allow that address when create `Upgrader` , e.g:

```
var origins = []string{ "http://127.0.0.1:18081", "http://localhost:18081", "http://example.com"}
var _ = websocket.Upgrader{
    // Resolve cross-domain problems
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        var origin = r.Header.Get("origin")
        for _, allowOrigin := range origins {
            if origin == allowOrigin {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }}
```